# How to make "{" key with xdotool

Tags: linux, xdotool

I have just switched to Linux A and I want to make custom macros and I decided to make them with the library called `xdotool`. I'm not sure if Python is used in Linux. My goal is to add a macro to easily press the "{" key, but it writes 0 using this code:

```
xdotool type "{}"
```

How can I print the `{` key?

Comment: Of course Python is used on Linux, too, but how is that revevant here?

Comment: And why do you have `"{}"` if you want `"{"`?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you're secretly doing something similar to `print(os.system('xdotool type "{}"'))` that ends up writing the exit code of the command

Comment: If I can put one "{", I can do the other one too. I think there is not much difference between putting one or two.tripleee

Comment: This code gave the following error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `os.system' that other guy

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the command you run and the 0 you see instead if `{`?

Answer (score 1):

Python is cross-platform, just install that and use a module like `pyautogui` or `keyboard` to send the inputs.

ex:

```py
# pyautogui
import pyautogui

pyautogui.write('{')

# -----------------------------
# keyboard

import keyboard

keyboard.send("shift+[")
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it using xdotool?